# Create assoc array from jQuery .each loop

Tags: jquery

A straight-forward jQuery `$.each` loop over a table row. I am not so good with objects and am running into difficulty with the `.push()` method.

I should be getting:

```
[{"buyerPoINPUT":"1234567"},{"jobINPUT":"Replace grommit"},{"shipMethodINPUT":"etc"}]
```

Instead, I am getting:

```
[{"t1":"1234567"},{"t1":"Replace grommit"},{"t1":"etc"}]
```

Why am I getting the `t1` variable name, repeated, instead of the `t1` var contents (id attribute)?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rp4godej/)

**HTML:**

```
    <div id="summaryTableDIV" class="b1">
        <table id="summaryTable">
            <thead>
                <th id="buyerPoTH">PO NO.</th><th id="jobTH">JOB</th><th id="shipMethodTH">SHIPPING<br>METHOD</th><th id="shipTermsTH">SHIPPING<br>TERMS</th><th id="payTermsTH">PAYMENT<br>TERMS</th><th id="blankTH"></th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <td id="buyerPoTD"   ><input type="text" id="buyerPoINPUT"    value="1234567" /></td>
                <td id="jobTD"       ><input type="text" id="jobINPUT"        value="Replace grommit" /></td>
                <td id="shipMethodTD"><input type="text" id="shipMethodINPUT" value="Loomis or DHL" /></td>
                <td id="shipTermsTD" ><input type="text" id="shipTermsINPUT"  value="FOB Washington" /></td>
                <td id="payTermsTD"  ><input type="text" id="shipMethodINPUT" value="see below" /></td>
                <td id="blankTD"     ><input type="text" id="blankINPUT" value="Okay to proceed" /></td>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div><!-- #summaryTableDIV -->
```

**js/jQ:**

```
var objSumTbl = new Array();

$("#summaryTable > tbody > tr > td > input").each(function(){
    var thisTD = $(this);
    var t1 = thisTD.attr('id');
    var t2 = thisTD.val();
    objSumTbl.push({
        t1 : t2
    });
});
alert( JSON.stringify(objSumTbl) );
```

Comment: Have you tried `objSumTbl.push ({ $(this).attr('id') : t2})` directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use object notation as {key:value}, 'key' will always be considered as a string constant instead of a variable name, you need to use object[key_name_var] notation.

This should work:

```
var thisTD = $(this);
var t1 = thisTD.attr('id');
var t2 = thisTD.val();
var new_obj = {};
new_obj[t1] = t2;
objSumTbl.push(new_obj);
```

---

Update: Based on our discussion in comments, your desired result should look like this:

```
{"buyerPoINPUT":"1234567","jobINPUT":"Replace grommit","shipMethodINPUT":"etc"}
```

Then you should define objSumTbl as a object, and use [key] notation to setup values inside the loop:

```
var objSumTbl = {};

$("#summaryTable > tbody > tr > td > input").each(function(){
    var thisTD = $(this);
    var t1 = thisTD.attr('id');
    var t2 = thisTD.val();
    objSumTbl[t1] = t2;
});
alert( JSON.stringify(objSumTbl) );
```

To iterate through all values inside a object, use

```
Object.keys(objSumTbl)
```

to get an array of all keys in objSumTbl, then do a for loop on that array:

```
var keys = Object.keys(objSumTbl);
for(i=0;i<keys.length;i++){
    console.log(objSumTbl[ keys[i] ]);
}
```

Comment: If I wanted the output to look like this, standard array, how would i do it: `["buyerPoINPUT":"1234567","jobINPUT":"Replace grommit","shipMethodINPUT":"etc"]` If possible, please edit your answer, and add response at bottom. *(The reason I ask is that I will be storing as json in a DB and I wish the easiest possible format for later retrieval, re-populating a new table)*

Comment: That's not a valid array notation, I think what you want is a object instead of an array? like {"buyerPoINPUT":"1234567","jobINPUT":"Replace grommit","shipMethodINPUT":"etc"}?

Comment: Yes, you are right !  And what would a loop look like to put everything back in the table?  (Not the IDs, they will be there already, just the data)

Comment: For saving, define objSumTbl as object and use objSumTbl[t1]=t2; in the loop. For loading, use Object.keys(objVarName) to get an array of keys objVarName has, then do a for loop on that array.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks. Accepted.  [Updated jsFiddle for future readers](http://jsfiddle.net/rp4godej/1/)

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that defining an object in JavaScript doesn't interpret the key part of the key/value pairs as variables.  This is literally naming the property `t1` instead of the value of the `t1` variable.

You *can*, however, create the object separately and use the variable to reference a property on the object to define that property.  Something like this:

```
var objSumTbl = new Array();

$("#summaryTable > tbody > tr > td > input").each(function(){
    var thisTD = $(this);
    var t1 = thisTD.attr('id');
    var t2 = thisTD.val();
    var newObj = {};
    newObj[t1] = t2;
    objSumTbl.push(newObj);
});
alert( JSON.stringify(objSumTbl) );
```

Answer (score 1):

thats not how you make an object property variable

try this way:

```
var objSumTbl = new Array();
$("#summaryTable > tbody > tr > td > input").each(function(){
    var thisTD = $(this);
    var t1 = thisTD.attr('id');
    var t2 = thisTD.val();
    var obj = {};
    obj[t1] = t2;
    objSumTbl.push(obj);
});

alert( JSON.stringify(objSumTbl) );
```